# special alt chars in html

Tags: html, ascii

I would like to print a solid right arrow and solid down arrow like the ones shown [here](http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/altchrc.html) when typing `alt+16 (►)` or `alt + 30 (▲)` in html

I tried echoing out all the characters up to `\004096` like this

```
 <?php
 For ($i=1;$i<16536;$i++){
    echo '&#'.$i.';&nbsp;'.$i.'<br>';
 }
 ?>
```

I went right through the arabic, chineese, thai etc but I couldn't find them

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alt+16 = ► = `&#9658;`

Alt+30 = ▲ = `&#9650;`

Your code snippet works fine though.

Comment: @andrew: Yeah, I have days like that too. Most days actually... :D